# Splitting up elements into groups of n child elements (follow-up from 69940580)

Tags: xslt-1.0

Follow-up from [insert page-break after all elements except the last, when position() is not reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69940580/insert-page-break-after-all-elements-except-the-last-when-position-is-not-rel).

How would I achieve the following result (more info below):

```
<pages>
    <page title="Manchuria">
        <edit version="2"/>
        <edit version="3"/>
    </page>
    <page-break/>
    <page title="Manchuria">
        <edit version="4"/>
        <edit version="5"/>
    </page>
    <page-break/>
    <page title="Manchuria">
        <edit version="6"/>
        <edit version="7"/>
    </page>
    <page-break/>
    <page title="Perfect the first time"/>
    <page-break/>
    <page title="Zombie Librarian">
        <edit version="2"/>
    </page>
</pages>
```

From the following input:

```
<articles>
    <article id="er113" title="Manchuria" publishable="true" version="7">
        <original>
            <article id="xc141" version="1"/>
        </original>
        <edits>
            <article id="er111" version="2"/>
            <article id="yu475" version="4"/>
            <article id="iu931" version="3"/>
            <article id="er111" version="5"/>
            <article id="er112" version="6"/>
            <article id="er113" version="7"/>
        </edits>
    </article>
    <article id="ww555" title="Perfect the first time" publishable="true" version="1">
        <original>
            <article id="ww555" version="1"/>
        </original>
        <edits/>
    </article>
    <article id="nb741" title="Zombie Librarian" publishable="true" version="2">
        <original>
            <article id="nc441" version="1"/>
        </original>
        <edits>
            <article id="nb741" version="2"/>
        </edits>
    </article>
</articles>
```

starting from the following xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <pages>
            <xsl:variable name="pages">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/articles/article[@publishable='true']" mode="subfilter"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            
            <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($pages)/article" mode="layout"/>
        </pages>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="article" mode="subfilter">
        <xsl:variable name="id_of_latest_edit">
            <xsl:for-each select="edits/article">
                <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="@version"/>
                <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="@id = $id_of_latest_edit or not(edits/article)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="article" mode="layout">
        <page title="{@title}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="edits/article" mode="editdetails"/>
        </page>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <page-break/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="article" mode="editdetails">
        <xsl:param name="editPos"/>
        <edit version="{@version}"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The problem**
A page can have maximum *n* edit elements (*n*=2 in this example), and the edits need to be sorted by version.

**What I tried**
Before the linked question was solved, I tried something along the lines of:

```
    <xsl:template match="article" mode="subfilter">
        <xsl:variable name="currentnode" select="."/>
        <!-- always print -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="layout"/>
        <!-- print extra pages when number of articles exceeds limit -->
        <xsl:if test="count(edits/article) > 2">
            <xsl:for-each select="edits/article[(position() mod 2) = 0]">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentnode" mode="layout"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

which gets me the multiple pages and I would still need to filter and sort the edit elements. However, the new code (to get the page-breaks) uses the node-set() function and I can't seem to figure out how to merge this approach (if it is even a good idea to try). Is maybe muenchian grouping needed?

Comment: What should be the result for an article with no edits?

Comment: It should just print the page element (no children). I updated the output and input xml to include that scenario (articled titled "Perfect the first time")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/articles">
    <pages>
        <xsl:variable name="pages">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="article[@publishable='true']" mode="preprocess"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($pages)/page"/>
    </pages>
</xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="article[not(edits/article)]" mode="preprocess">
    <page title="{@title}"/>
</xsl:template> 
    
<xsl:template match="article" mode="preprocess">
    <xsl:variable name="title" select="@title" />
    <xsl:for-each select="edits/article">
        <xsl:sort select="@version" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
            <page title="{$title}">
                <edit version="{@version}"/>
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                    <edit version="{@version + 1}"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </page>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="page">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <page-break/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes versions are numbered consecutively.